# Missing LSB Information (Start-up Shell Script)

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, runlevel

I created an auto start shell script. Then I have given permission to be executable.

```
Add a link to /etc/inin.d/ :   sudo ln -snf /opt/myapp/apimanager /etc/init.d/apimanager
```

update-rc.d command to set the run levels

```
sudo update-rc.d apimanager defaults
```

I end up with below error

```
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/apimanager missing LSB information
update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts>
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/apimanager ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20apimanager -> ../init.d/apimanager
   /etc/rc1.d/K20apimanager -> ../init.d/apimanager
   /etc/rc6.d/K20apimanager -> ../init.d/apimanager
   /etc/rc2.d/S20apimanager -> ../init.d/apimanager
   /etc/rc3.d/S20apimanager -> ../init.d/apimanager
   /etc/rc4.d/S20apimanager -> ../init.d/apimanager
   /etc/rc5.d/S20apimanager -> ../init.d/apimanager
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To get rid of the warning we have to add the corresponding script header as described [here](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts).

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```